# Searching a grid of points, visting each point once only

Tags: java, search, grid

I have a grid of (d) dimensions, all dimensions are partitioned using delta = 0.25

An example of this grid is this figure (d here is 2, and each dimension is normalized 0-1):

[image]

Each intersection represents 1 point, for example, the point in the middle is represented as:

```
double[] A={0.5, 0.5};
```

My question is:
I want to search this grid, starting from an input point A and its neighbors. Then continue doing that. With one condition: Each point is visited only once.

To clarify more, consider this example:
The starting point is:

```
double[] A={0.5, 0.5};
```

So, A is checked first, then its neighbours are generated and inserted into a Queue (the queue is ordered based on a function f).

[image]

Here point A is the dark circle . Its neighbors are the green circles:

```
{0.25, 0.25}
{0.25, 0.5}
{0.25, 0.75}
..
..
..
{0.75, 0.75}
```

Now, the algorithm loops until the Queue becomes empty.
In the loop, the top point is removed (pop()), then checked, then its *neighbors* are added to the Queue.

[image]

For example, in the first loop, the blue circle happened to be the top point in the Queue.
It is removed from the Queue, then checked, then its neighbors (red circles) are generated and added to the Queue.

The problem here is, my code that generates the neighbors points, does not know if a previous point is visited before or not.

and I cannot keep a list of previously visited points, and check it every time a new point is generated ( with high dimensions and high resolution  e.g., d=8 and delta= 0.03125, it will take for ever!)

This is the search algorithm:

```
public void search(int d, double delta, double[] inpoint)
{
    Queue queue = new Queue();
    queue.push(inpoint);

    while( !queue.isEmpty() )
    {
        // remove top point from Queue
        double[] a = queue.pop();

        // Check point a and do some calculations
        // ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

        // Generate neighbours of current point:
        ArrayList<double[]> neighbors = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        nextMoves(a, new double[d], delta, d, neighbors);

        // For each point in neighbors, push to Queue:
        for( int i=0 ; i < neighbors.size(), i++ )
            queue.push(neighbors.get(i));
    }
}
```

And this is the algorithm for generating the neighbors, it is a recursive algorithm.

```
public static void nextMoves(double[] inatt, double[] outatt, double delta, int d, ArrayList<double[]> neighbors) 
{
    if( d == inatt.length )
    {
        if( !outOfBound(outatt,d) )
        {
            moves.add(outatt);   
        }
    }
    else
    {
       // first case: add delta:
       outatt[d] = inatt[d]+delta; 
       nextMoves( inatt, outatt, delta, d+1, moves);

       // second case: subtract delta:
       outatt[d] = inatt[d]-delta; 
       nextMoves( inatt, outatt, delta, d+1, moves);

       // third case: no change:
       outatt[d] = inatt[d]; 
       nextMoves( inatt, outatt, delta, d+1, moves);
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, keeping a list of previously visited points is not a possible solution. 
If I do this, then the list becomes very large when I have high dimensionality and high resolution. 
And this list will have to be searched linearly each time a point is created!

Perhaps I should organize this list in a spatial index? I don't know... 
I would appreciate your input.

Comment: Can you tell us what operation you intend to perform at each point?  I doubt that there is any real world problem where you plan to "visit" each point without doing something there.

Comment: `And this list will have to be searched linearly each time a point is created` ... no, you won't have to search the entire list to check for a duplicate point if you can simply _access_ an array using the point in question.

Comment: Is your Queue class FIFO (first-in-first-out) ? and does it allow to check if the element is already present in the Queue ?

Comment: @TarunGupta Yes it is FIFO. The current code does not check if the queue already has the point to be added. This is actually where the check I want to add should be. If you look at the nextMoves() function, after checking that the point is within bounds, then here I should check if it is already in the queue or not, and if it has been visited before or not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Believe me, if you set d=10 and delta = 0.03125, you end up with a HUGE number of points, that will take forever to check!.

Comment: @user1728624 I think you have the wrong approach here.  You will have constant lookup time if you store your past moves inside an array.  And you never told us what calculation you might be doing at each point.  In reality, you would likely already have some state stored in an N-dimensional array for each point.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope, the lookup time will not constant. It depends on how many points I have in the "previously visited" array. I don't know what will change if I tell you what kind of calculation I'm doing, knowing that won't change anything يا ملقوف

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of potential shortcuts you could consider:

1. You could remove points from your 'previously visited' list once all surrounding points have been added. The reasoning is simple: they can only be added from surrounding points. This means only the surface of the visited volume needs to be in the list. At higher dimensions this would be a substantial saving.
2. More complicated would be to store the shape of the volume rather than the points. This would mean recording each inflection point on the surface of the volume and testing if each new point is on that surface.

The first is simpler but not as efficient. I'd suggest starting with that and seeing if it's enough.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to store all visited points. Going around and collect first all neighbours and build a hashkey out of this points to store this in a hashmap. Then validate all this points with your code and collect the next circle of neighbours. In the worst case you started in the middle. Then the calculationtime of the hashkeys are high at the end of the algortihm. To solve this problem you can build cluster and search within the cluster first.

You can start with clustering too. Build up a cluster layout and start to search within this cluster with the above circle method.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to a pathfinding problem where you might also parse a grid and don't unnecessarily want to revisit nodes.
If it works for you, set a boolean on each visited node, so if the algorithm happens upon it again, it knows it doesn't need to check it.
Look at [Djikstras Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) for inspiration.

Comment: The problem is the multidimensionality and a full connected graph. Djikstra is not a good solution because its works fine for 2D and not if you have 8D. You will have to take Ant-Algorithm or Particle Swarm Optimization. But these are Metaheuristics with stocahstical elements and didnt give you the optimal solution back with every run.